# xticks labels don't get displayed in Julia Plots (with pyplot backend)

Tags: matplotlib, julia, xticks, julia-plots

I am basically trying to use this feature described in the Julia plots [documentation](http://docs.juliaplots.org/latest/attributes/#)

```
plot!(xticks = ([0:π:3*π;], ["0", "\\pi", "2\\pi"]))
```

My example looks like this:

```
using Plots
dat = rand(60*60*50)
pyplot()
plot(
    dat,
    xticks = ([0:10*60*50:60*60*50;], ["0", "10", "20", "30", "40", "50", "60"]),
    xlabel = "time [min]"
    )
```

The code creates the ticks, but does not label them:

[image: Output]

This code worked before the latest update. Did anyone experience this problem as well (and has a solution)?

Comment: __Julia 1.6__ (May 2021): Works for me. It may have been a bug that has been fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `xformatter` option to display tick values.

This produces the result you have in mind.

```
Plots.plot(
     dat,
     xticks=0:30000:180000,
     xformatter = ((x) -> "\$$(round(Int,x/(60*50)))\$"),
     xlabel = "time [min]")
```

[image: Plots.jl using xformatter]

Comment: Is there a reason the syntax `xticks = ([0:π:3*π;], ["0", "\\pi", "2\\pi"]` does not work anymore?

Comment: I do not know honestly - I remember `xticks` did not work for me neither and started using `xformatter` which is even nicer and more powerful. Maybe someone else will add an alternative answer? Maybe API has changed?